# On hover absolute element but keep other elements at start position

Tags: css

Sorry but I don't know how to ask/search that because of my bad English.

I have div elements that is float left each other. 
I want when mouse over in one div to change width with transition and overlapping the other on right.

HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" style="background:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background:green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  float:left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s ;
}
.box:hover{
  width: 155px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbvd86z8/)

In the example I have 3 boxes (red, green and blue)
when mouse over on red, the green box going on left:0 (don't wont that)
I want to stay at position and red box overlaps the green, same when mouse over on green box to overlap the blue one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using floats and changing width on hover you can use `inline-block` to position elements inline and `transform: scaleX()` to change element width on hover. Also you need to add `transform-origin: left` to make element scale from left to right.

```css
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform-origin: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box:hover{
 transform: scaleX(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" style="background:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background:green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct answer but maybe I wasn't clear, Actually each box has text that is hidden over the 100px, and if the width change not scale the text will be appear.